# What is the best alternative for a native app using webviews interfacing with a C# web based application?

Tags: c#, android, ios, webview, telerik

I am building an android + iOS app that has its own functionality as well as incorporates functionality of another web based application.

I am using [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/platform) to build out the interfaces, and probably OAuth to handle the sign-on.

I do however have the issue of handling portions of the C# functionality within my app, and I wanted to know what the best way was to interface between the database of the C# app.

There are obviously many rules associated with each action. For example, if a student uses the android app and wants to upload a grade to the (previously handled by C# web app) database, how do I go about doing this? Do I have to rebuild all functionality within my app? Is there a way I can use API's to retrieve info defining rules?

I am very against `WebView`s as it is slow and clunky.

Apologies if I seem silly here, not very experienced in the matter.

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So, Basically you wanted to go for cross platform mobile application Development !!

Then you have lots of options where you can use your web based knowledge to build mobile application

Like , Phonegap , Titanium and many more , there you can just use you own web based knowledge and make good Mobile application

http://phonegap.com/

http://www.appcelerator.com/

also , if you wanted to go for c# only then i suggest you to go for 
xamarin

http://xamarin.com/

Also you will get so many api and guide for that about sqlite and also so many good designs are also available in this all platforms !

Do let me know if you need more information !!

Happy Coding !!

Comment: Yes, cross platform is a must, hence telerik as my decision. I am just a bit lost as to how I can interface with the database (MS SQL), without having to replicate the C# app from the ground up. How do I adopt certain rules from the C# app to be used in mine? Webviews will not work as its too clunky, and not 'mobile feeling'. I want to be able to perform a portion of the functions, with a portion of the rules. Where do I start here?

Comment: Okay , so you can find some best tutorials there ! also they are arrange some good webinars , you must attend that !

please check the webinars dates and all from same website !! or you can contact them for queries and question , even they have forum so you can post some questions there ! !

so , you will get answer there !